# Issues with a deprecated function

Tags: android

So here's the issue:
I have to implement google pay, but unfortunately it keeps crashing while I click on my payment button: here's the code:

```
    mBoutonCommandeFinale.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener( ) {
 
       @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Uri infos = new Uri.Builder( )
                    .scheme("upi")
                    .authority("pay")
                    .appendQueryParameter("pa", "test@axisbank")
                    .appendQueryParameter("pn", "Test Merchant")
                    .appendQueryParameter("mc", "1234")
                    .appendQueryParameter("tr", "123456789")
                    .appendQueryParameter("tn", "test transaction note")
                    .appendQueryParameter("am", "10.01")
                    .appendQueryParameter("cu", "INR")
                    .appendQueryParameter("url", "https://test.merchant.website")
                    .build( );
            Intent payView = new Intent( );
            payView.setData(infos);
            payView.setPackage(GOOGLE_PAY_PACKAGE_NAME);
            startActivityForResult(payView, GOOGLE8PAY_REQUEST_CODE);

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == GOOGLE8PAY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        Log.d("result", "oups! la sauce était trop bonne et l'application n'a pas pu se connecter! ");
    }
```

I don't know why it has been deprecated, and need to fix this rapidly, So I can go through another function.
Can anyone help me to find a solution, So I can go through another function to try to finish the application.

Comment: If it's crashing, post the stack trace.

Comment: had to completely rework it, nwo due to the deprecated function it just doesn't start the activity.

Comment: Did you [read the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result)?